# Pagination Link

Tags: php, html, laravel

What is the correct way to call the "Links" function after this "Foreach"?
I don't know how to handle the variable to put in function.

```
@inject('usuarios', 'App\User')
 @foreach($usuarios->getIndicados() as $user)

@endforeach

<div class="row">
<div class="col-12 text-center">
{{ $usuarios->getIndicados()->links() }}
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: {!!$users->render() !!} It is enough

Comment: Sorry, but still returning error. " Call to undefined method App\User::render() "

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's just an editing error, but in your output the -tags don't seem to be closed again. Also, there should be no space like < a> at the beginning of the tag. And < a hr_ef= ... is obviously wrong.

In order to style them, you can add a class attribute to the tags while building the string and do the style-stuff in css.

Comment: Below Foreach, I only have <thead> with <td>, because stackoverflow did not allow posting, the reality is that I do not know which variable before "Links"

Answer (score 0):

This is what laravel document provides. You need to add links in the collection.

```
<div class="container">
@foreach ($users as $user)
    {{ $user->name }}
@endforeach
```

{{ $users->links() }}

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it's only working with Foreach that was posted = '(

Comment: How would it be creating with the variable "@foreach($usuarios->getIndicados() as $user)"?

Comment: If you can't find any solution then  best alternative is to use $user = $usuarios->getIndicados(); in your controller and return the variables as $users. Then may be you can use standard laravel format to paginate links